# Pandas DataFrame iloc spoils the data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Having pandas 0.19.2.

Here's an example:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})
testdf.dtypes
```

Output:

```
A      int64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Everything looks fine for now, but what I don't like is that (note, that first call is a `pd.Series.iloc` and the second one is `pd.DataFrame.iloc`)

```
print(type(testdf.A.iloc[0]))
print(type(testdf.iloc[0].A))
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I found it while trying to understand why `pd.DataFrame.join()` operation returned almost no intersections of two `int64` columns while there should be many. 
My guess is because of type inconsistency which might be connected with this behaviour, but I'm not sure... My short investigation revealed the thing above and now I'm confused a bit.

If someone knows how to solve it - I'll be very grateful for any hints!

**UPD**

Thanks to @EdChum for comments. So here is the example with my generated data and join/merge behaviour

`testdf.join(testdf, on='A', rsuffix='3')`

```
    A   B   A3  B3 
0   1   1.0 2.0 2.0
1   2   2.0 3.0 3.0
2   3   3.0 4.0 4.0
3   4   4.0 NaN NaN
```

And what is considered to be quite the same
`pd.merge(left=testdf, right=testdf, on='A')`
returns

```
    A   B_x B_y
0   1   1.0 1.0
1   2   2.0 2.0
2   3   3.0 3.0
3   4   4.0 4.0
```

**UPD2** Replicating @EdChum comment on `join` and `merge` behaviour. The problem is that `A.join(B, on='C')` will use index in `A` and join it with column `B['C']`, since by default join uses index. In my case I just used merge to get desireable result.

Comment: `iloc` returns a series of your row, there is no dtype that will satisfy both int and float hence `object` is shown, what's the problem here as your row is a mixed dtype?

Comment: if your columns you're trying to match are int64 then value comparison should work as expected, if they're float then this may run into precision problems, this has nothing to do with what you're showing above

Comment: @EdChum Well, thanks, your point explains my example. My columns are not float, so this is a problem somewhere. For example, I can manually find specified value in both tables, however, join fails for it.

Comment: It sounds like you have a data problem, if your values don't match exactly then they won't join/merge you need to solve that issue first. try `merge` and pass a list of columns to `on=`, if have missing values in a column then the dtype becomes float, additionally trying to merge `NaN` will introduce errors, you need to decide whether to replace these or drop them but I can't tell without seeing your data and code of your real problem

Comment: @EdChum just checked. `pd.merge` works fine. `DataFrame.join()` fails with the same code. I'll try to make an example

Comment: note `join` by default tries to join on index, `merge` will try to merge on columns, they are semantically different but you can get the same results depending on params passed

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that should be the problem

Comment: Huh, that seems like possibly an error with `join` & `on='A'`.  It appears to be joining from the **index** of the first df to the **column** 'A' of the second df (4 appears in the column but not the index, hence the nans).  I dunno if that is expected or not...  But in line with @EdChum's comment I would only use `join` for an index to index merge and would use `merge` for any other type of merge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is as expected.  `pandas` tracks `dtypes` per column.  When you call `testdf.iloc[0]` you are asking pandas for a row.  It has to convert the entire row into a series.  That row contained a float.  Therefore the row as a series must be float.

However, it seems that when pandas uses `loc` or `iloc` it makes this conversion when you use a single `__getitem__`

Here are some interesting test cases for a `testdf` with one `int` column

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

print(type(testdf.iloc[0].A))
print(type(testdf.A.iloc[0]))

<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Change it to OP test case

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})

print(type(testdf.iloc[0].A))
print(type(testdf.A.iloc[0]))

<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>

print(type(testdf.loc[0, 'A']))
print(type(testdf.iloc[0, 0]))
print(type(testdf.at[0, 'A']))
print(type(testdf.iat[0, 0]))
print(type(testdf.get_value(0, 'A')))

<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So, it appears that when `pandas` uses `loc` or `iloc` it makes some conversions across rows which I still don't fully understand.  I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that the nature of `loc` and `iloc` are different than `at`, `iat`, `get_value` in that `iloc` and `loc` allow you to access the dataframe with index arrays and boolean arrays.  While `at`, `iat`, and `get_value` only access a single cell at a time.

---

Despite that

```
testdf.loc[0, 'A'] = 10

print(type(testdf.at[0, 'A']))
```

When we assign to that location via `loc`, `pandas` ensures the `dtype` stays consistent.