# Pandas returns different datetime formats with iloc vs. with condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am struggling to get consistent datetime formatting out of a pandas array. I have a `df` with a calendar date colum of dtype `datetime64[ns]`.

When I access the calendar date directly by iloc, say index 966, I get a `Timestamp` type

```
df.iloc[966]['Calendar Day']
```

Output 1:

```
Timestamp('1998-09-26 00:00:00')
```

However, when access the same line with a conditional statement, I get a different output format

```
a = df[ (df['colA'] == condA ) & (df['colB'] == condB ))]['Calendar Day']
a
```

results in output 2:

```
966   1998-09-26
Name: Calendar Day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

My condition is designed such that I can only report at most 1 line, or nan.

I am puzzled: The 2 statement look equal to me, given both times I access the same col of the same row of the same df, once by index, once by condition.

How do I make them equal? I would like to calculate a different, such as

```
abs( (a-b).days )
```

to get the relative time difference. That results in `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalar index value passed to `iloc` gives you a scalar value in return (timestamp in this case), while boolean masking gives you a `pd.Series` in return. So you neither have different formatting, nor different datatypes.

***scalar index:***

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['1998-09-25', '1998-09-26', '1998-09-27']),
                   'v0': [1,2,3], 'v1': [4,5,6]})

# a scalar index value gives you a specific value from one row/column:
df.iloc[1]['date']
# Timestamp('1998-09-26 00:00:00')
```

***boolean masking:***

```
# this gives you a series with one element:
# mask:
m = (df['v0'] == 2) & (df['v1'] == 5)
# note that m is also a series, not a scalar value:
# 0    False
# 1    True
# 2    False
# Name: v0, dtype: bool

df[m]['date']
# ...and so is the result if you apply the mask:
# 1   1998-09-26
# Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

***same dtype actually...***

```
# note that the dtype also timestamp:
df[m]['date'].iloc[0]
# Timestamp('1998-09-26 00:00:00')
```

***vs. index slice:***

```
df.iloc[1:2]['date'] # ...also gives you pd.Series
# 1   1998-09-26
# Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

***...to get the arithmetic working*** use the dt accessor (since you're working with a Series):

```
a, b = df.iloc[1]['date'], df[m]['date']
abs( (a-b).dt.days )
# 1    0
# Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because `df.iloc[966]` creates a Series object when given only one index and the types are all changed to a common dtype, whereas in your version with conditional statement there is no type conversion because no Series object is created.
You can confirm this by replacing `df.iloc[966]` with `df.iloc[966:967]` and check that you get same type than with conditional statement.
See [Pandas DataFrame iloc spoils the data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662881/pandas-dataframe-iloc-spoils-the-data-type)

Comment: I don't see any type conversion at all... the first statement just returns a specific element from a column of the df, while the boolean mask returns a pd.Series

Comment: It is implicitly done by Pandas because df.iloc[966] accesses a single row so it needs to create a Series object for that row with a common dtype for all colums. See my link.

Comment: my point is that there actually is no difference in dtypes; a Series of dtype datetime holds objects of dtype Timestamp.

Comment: also, I think your linked question / example is not applicable - it shows int and float dtypes - of which float is the "more general" one - which is why it is used *in this case* in the returned value.

Comment: Yes maybe it is not this exact problem here but without any additional information I think my answer is useful as there is usage of iloc with single index and there is a type issue.

Comment: I've added an answer, implicitly showing why the question here is not about type conversion. `pandas` behavior in the question you linked is strange but a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case was that i had NAN values in the dataframe.
After `df.dropna(inplace=True)` it was returning the original dataformat.